ADO.NET Provider for OpenLink Virtuoso for .NET 8.0?
In old projects I am using the OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso provider to access data stored in a Virtuoso server. I now want to upgrade these projects to .NET 8.0 - but I cannot find any update to the provider I used before (it's from 2015).
How can I access (read/write) data to a Virtuoso server with .NET 8.0?
Thanks in advance,
Frank
I searched the web but all I found was the old provider for ADO.NET 3.5

Virtuoso-specific questions like this may be better raised to the OpenLink Community Forum or the Virtuoso Open Source project on GitHub.

You need to install these packages first for net 8 to communicate with virtuoso
dotnet add package OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso

dotnet add package VirtuosoProvider

after that you can use them like this
using System.Data;
using OpenLink.Data.Virtuoso;

var connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=1111;User ID=dba;Password=dba;Database=Virtuoso";

using (var conn = new VirtuosoConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    VirtuosoCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SPARQL SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 10";

    using (VirtuosoDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0] + " " + reader[1] + " " + reader[2]);
        }
    }
}



Hey n_dev, thanks for your reply. I tried that in a new project and it worked to some extend (I guess when upgrading from .NET-Framework the necessary files to run a .NET-Framework resource in .NET 8.0 were not installed).
Though I run in another problem ... the assembly System.EnterpriseServices could not be loaded. I installed it to the GAC with gacutil, but the error persists. I checked the GAC and the assembly is there (with correct public key), but just the line "System.EnterpriseServices.resources" - though this a complete new question to be asked ...

It's my pleasure  but the nature of net frame work and net 8 is totally different  basically both use c# but on the configuration level they are totally different so that's why you are facing the issue.
